# How to migrate from Cloud Datastore to Cloud Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, database-migration, google-cloud-spanner

I'm looking at dataflow to try to export data from Datastore to Spanner. Spanner seems to only accept avro files via a dataflow connector. The only dataflow template I can find is from datastore to text-files. And the datastore export service is only exporting into levelDB format.
Any clue would be helpful, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up with was extracting the data as csv, then converting to Avro with PySpark. And finally inserting with Dataflow into Spanner.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible route is to export from Datastore to BigQuery [1]. BigQuery can then export to Avro file into GCS [2], which can be imported to Cloud Spanner [3].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

[3] https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/import-non-spanner

Answer (score 1):

There are guides for migrating from other relational databases such as MySQL or PostgreSQL to Spanner but I could not find any guide if you would like to migrate data from a NoSQL db such as Datastore to a relational DB such as Spanner.

One thing you could try is Dataflow. Dataflow reads from Datastore (either forklift or do some data processing) then write to Spanner using SpannerIO.  [I/O transforms](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/). [Querying Datastore with Python](https://medium.com/@mwebler/apache-beam-tricks-querying-google-datastore-with-python-1bd9d9cecf73) may also give you an idea.